# Refresh scope on every x time using $timeout

Tags: angularjs, timeout, angularjs-scope

I am a newbie to angular. I want to use $timeout of angular to refresh scope after few minutes. I am working on an social app where i need to refresh notification scope after few minutes. Getting notification from a http request using service.

JS:

```
App.factory('MyService' ,function($scope,$timeout){
return{
 notification:return function(callback){
      $timeout(function(){
       $http.get("notification/get").success(callback)
      },100000);


}
}); 

function Controller($scope,MyService){

 MyService.notification(function(result){
  $scope.notification =data;
 });
```

}

Now how can i make http request after few minutes let'say 1 minute and refresh notification scope. I tried using $timeout but things are not working fine.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

But i would suggest to move the `$interval` to the controller.

```
 App.factory('MyService' ,function($scope,$timeout){
  return{
    notification: function(){
        return $http.get("notification/get").success(function(response){
           return response.data;
        });          
    }
  }); 

function Controller($scope,MyService,$interval){  

   /**
   * Loads and populates the notifications
   */
   this.loadNotifications = function (){
      MyService.notification().then(function(data){
        $scope.notification =data;
      });
   });
   //Put in interval, first trigger after 10 seconds 
   var theInterval = $interval(function(){
      this.loadNotifications();
   }.bind(this), 10000);    

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $interval.cancel(theInterval)
    });

   //invoke initialy
   this.loadNotifications();
}
```

This seems like a better architecture there.

Passing, resolving or rejecting promises will `$digest` the scope. 
You want to get the notifications every x milliseconds and pass them into the scope.

Comment: How can we make first call on page load and then further goes after let's say 10sec. ?

Comment: Remember that you have to manually cancel the interval:  `$scope.$on('$destroy', function () { $interval.cancel(theInterval) })`

Comment: Moving to web sockets would be better, rather than pull, you can push to the client https://github.com/wilk/ng-websocket

Comment: Websockets will force your middleware/backend to be stateful, will turn your architecture and are not working in IE 8-10(?). There are some problems with load balancers and proxies, but yeah WS are great.

Answer (score 1):

You want to instantiate the timeout after it finishes. Try changing your $timeout function to something like:

```
var timer = $timeout( function refresh(){
    $http.get("notification/get").success(callback)
    timer = $timeout(refresh, 100000);
}, 100000);
```

Comment: How can we make first call on page load and then further goes after let's say 10sec. ?