# how to refresh the chart in every 30 seconds using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i want to reload the chart in every 30 seconds using angular js. how to reload chart to show latest values.how to use setInterval(function() in angular js ? how to reload the fusion chart in every 30 seconds.

code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ng-fusioncharts"]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {


    $scope.chartData = {
        "chart": {
            "caption": "chart 1",
            "lowerLimit": "0",
            "upperLimit": "100",
            "showValue": "1",
            "valueBelowPivot": "1",
            "theme": "fint",
            "width": '50%',
            "height": '50%'
        },
        "colorRange": {
            "color": [{
                "minValue": "0",
                "maxValue": "30",
                "code": "#6baa01"
            }, {
                "minValue": "31",
                "maxValue": "70",
                "code": "#f8bd19"
            }, {
                "minValue": "71",
                "maxValue": "100",
                "code": "#e44a00"
            }]
        },
        "dials": {
            "dial": [{
                "value": "@Model[0].Filled.ToString("N2")"
           }]
        }
    };
});



       <div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
                <fusioncharts id="chartContainer1" width="300" height="300" type="angulargauge" datasource={{chartData}}></fusioncharts>
<div>
```

Comment: `$interval` with `30000` time would make the trick(*Note: don't forget to clear async event in `$destroy` event*)

Comment: If you are trying to acheive real time update, i would suggest trying to use socket technologie.

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/timeout-interval.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541857/refresh-scope-on-every-x-time-using-timeout

Comment: agree with @Nicolas and suggest the use of socket instead of $interval ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To refresh your chart on certain interval, you can make use of FusionCharts API method feedData() which will feed updated data on each interval, this will work under rendered api event which is triggered when the chart completes drawing.

Created a sample fiddle using your data where the dial value is updated after each 5 seconds:
   http://jsfiddle.net/ayanbhaduryfc/1waau2hw/

```
<html ng-app="HelloApp">

<body ng-controller="MyController">
<div>
  <fusioncharts id="mychartcontainer" chartid="mychart" width="550"     height="270" type="angulargauge" dataSource="{{dataSource}}" events="events">  </fusioncharts>

 <script>
   var app = angular.module('HelloApp', ["ng-fusioncharts"])
 app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

 $scope.events = {
 "rendered": function(evtObj, argObj) {
  var intervalVar = setInterval(function() {
    var chartIns = evtObj.sender,
      prcnt = 65 + parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10), 10);

    chartIns.feedData("value=" + prcnt);

  }, 5000);
  }


 };

  $scope.dataSource = {
  "chart": {
  "caption": "chart 1",
  "lowerLimit": "0",
  "upperLimit": "100",
  "showValue": "1",
  "valueBelowPivot": "1",
  "theme": "fint",
  "width": '50%',
  "height": '50%'
},
"colorRange": {
  "color": [{
    "minValue": "0",
    "maxValue": "30",
    "code": "#6baa01"
  }, {
    "minValue": "31",
    "maxValue": "70",
    "code": "#f8bd19"
  }, {
    "minValue": "71",
    "maxValue": "100",
    "code": "#e44a00"
  }]
},
"dials": {
  "dial": [{
    "value": "54"
  }]
}
};

});
 </script>

 </div>
</body>
 </html>
```